# Using the find method in excel

Tags: excel, error-handling, find, vba

I am struggling to figure out how to figure out if the search string is not found in excel, i tried

```
isnothing(rFoundCell)
```

but this does not work, says method can not be found

and the iserror also does not work

```
   For rCount = Settings.rowHeaderTempFile + 1 To lRow2
    Set rFoundCell = Range("A" & Settings.rowHeader + 1)
    Set rFoundCell = ws.Columns(1).Find(What:=ws2.Cells(rCount,
                     partNumberWs2).Value, After:=rFoundCell, 
                     LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, 
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext,
                     MatchCase:=False)

    If IsError(rFoundCell.Row) Then ' fails here
        lRow = lRow + 1
```

Comment: Can you post the full code(including declarations of variables), not just a *piece* of it...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `rFoundCell` is `Nothing` it doesn't have a `.Row` property.
`If rFoundCell Is Nothing` seems to be more convenient for handling, but in real life situations I wouldn't use handling, the dependent procedure should be based on an `If Not rFoundCell Is Nothing Then` criterium.

```
For rCount = Settings.rowHeaderTempFile + 1 To lRow2
    Set rFoundCell = Range("A" & Settings.rowHeader + 1)
    Set rFoundCell = ws.Columns(1).Find(What:=ws2.Cells(rCount,
                     partNumberWs2).Value, After:=rFoundCell, 
                     LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, 
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext,
                     MatchCase:=False)
If Not rFoundCell Is Nothing Then
    'do stuff
Else
    lRow = lRow + 1
End If
```

Comment: `isnothing(rFoundCell)` was what i found on google, but obvisoly the syntax was `rFoundCell is Nothing` Now the code work flawless, it copys cells from another workbook if it can not be found in the active one. thanks  @user3819867